# Select item with comma separated data-attribute

Tags: jquery

Considering the following:

```
<option value="de" data-countries="at,ch,li">German</option>
```

How can I make a jQuery selector that sets this option as the selected one? (With `ccl` being the lowercase country code)

```
if ($("#select option[value='"+ccl+"']").length > 0) {
    select.val(ccl); // Pick this one
} else {
    $("#select:contains("+ccl+")").attr('selected', 'selected'); // Pick one from the country list
}
```

This one doesn't really work, because the `:contains` doesn't know where to search really.

Edit: I have full control over the source code, so if the comma separated list isn't ideal, I can change things.

Comment: what is ccl is referring?

Comment: Your question isn't quite clear to me, but still you can loop over the options, get the data attribute, and check if it contains your `ccl` value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to look by the data-attribute itself, and use the `*=` wildcard (which searches for it anywhere) within it.

```
$('#select option[data-countries*="' + ccl + '"]')
```

Example shown here:

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qNRs8/)**

Comment: After your 2nd edit it works.. I had something like this, but not the `option` part. This works now, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

The previous answer will get you wrong select if two words has same letters in different options for Example

```
<option value="us" data-countries="atx,chy">US</option>
<option value="de" data-countries="at,ch,li">German</option>
```

In the above example if you used the previous answer it will with value "at" it will select the first option also ( which is wrong )!

---

#### The below is the correct implementation:

http://jsfiddle.net/E9qXe/

```
$(function () {
    ccl = 'tx';
    $('#select option').each(function(){
        countries = $(this).attr('data-countries');
        val = $(this).attr('value');
        var countriesArr = countries.split(",");
        if(jQuery.inArray(ccl,countriesArr) > -1){
           $('#select').val(val); 
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Good point. But with 2 letter country code that won't be a problem. Up'ed it anyway!